# How to use aggregateBykey to get a list of value per key?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let say we have an rdd containing element where each is as following:

```
(studentName, course, grade):

("Joseph", "Maths", 83), ("Joseph", "Physics", 74), ("Joseph", "Chemistry", 91), ("Joseph", "Biology", 82), 
  ("Jimmy", "Maths", 69), ("Jimmy", "Physics", 62), ("Jimmy", "Chemistry", 97), ("Jimmy", "Biology", 80), 
  ("Tina", "Maths", 78), ("Tina", "Physics", 73), ("Tina", "Chemistry", 68)
```

my target is to get another rdd consists of `(StudentName, [(course, grade)])` using `aggregateBykey`:

```
("Joseph", [("Maths", 83),("Physics", 74), ("Chemistry", 91), ("Biology", 82)]) 
  ("Jimmy", [("Maths", 69), ("Physics", 62), ("Chemistry", 97), ("Biology", 80)])
  ("Tina", [("Maths", 78), ("Physics", 73), ("Chemistry", 68)])
```

I tried the following:

```
zero_val = []

student_list_rdd = studentRDD(lambda u: (u[0], (u[1], u[2]))).aggregateByKey(zero_val, seq_op, comb_op) 

def seq_op(accumulator, element):
    if element not in accumulator:
        return element
    return accumulator

# Combiner Operation : Finding Maximum Marks out Partition-Wise Accumulators
def comb_op(accumulator1, accumulator2):
    return accumulator1 + accumulator2
```

But i got the following result:

```
("Joseph", ("Maths", 83,"Physics", 74, "Chemistry", 91, "Biology", 82) 
      ("Jimmy", ("Maths", 69, "Physics", 62, "Chemistry", 97, "Biology", 80)
      ("Tina", ("Maths", 78, "Physics", 73, "Chemistry", 68)
```

Some hint to get the desired ouptut will be so appreciated?

How can we do the same if we have a pyspark dataframe with three columns:
`<student, course, grade>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `aggregateByKey`, `groupBy` should work. Just `groupBy` the first value, and then transform each group by removing the first value from each tuple:

```py
rdd.groupBy(lambda x: x[0]).mapValues(lambda g: [x[1:] for x in g]).collect()

# [('Jimmy', [('Maths', 69), ('Physics', 62), ('Chemistry', 97), ('Biology', 80)]), 
#  ('Tina', [('Maths', 78), ('Physics', 73), ('Chemistry', 68)]), 
#  ('Joseph', [('Maths', 83), ('Physics', 74), ('Chemistry', 91), ('Biology', 82)])]
```

Comment: please how can we do the same if we have a dataframe with three columns student, course, grade?